# Calculating how many times a number is added to itself until it reaches an arbitrary value?

Tags: java

Considering two variables:

"n" is any arbitrary value.

"i" is the number of times a value is increased in a sum before it reaches the value of "n".

So for instance if the value n = 344 is chosen, then i = 26 because:

26 + 25 + 24 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = 351

26 is how many times the variable "i" gets added together in a descending order before it either is equal to n = 344 or the first time it surpasses.

```
public class Trstuff{
    public static void main (String [] arg) {
        int n = 4;
        int i = computeIndex(n);
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    public static int computeIndex(int n) {
        int i = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        for(i = 1; sum <= n; i++) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

My goal is to choose any "n" value and then have the program return the variable "i" to me.

As my program stands, I thought it should be correct, but somehow it's not. Here is the example with n = 4.

The result should be that "i = 3" because:

```
1 + 2 = 3

1 + 2 + 3 = 6
```

So the ascending value of "i" in the loop is added 3 times before the loop supposedly should stop because of the expression "sum <= n" in the loop.

However, when I run the program it returns the value 4 instead. I simply cannot figure out what is wrong and why my program  gives me 4 instead of the correct answer, 3?

Comment: To be direct, it's because your program isn't correct. You should look at this with a debugger and verify the `for` behaves as you expect. In this case does `i` stay at the correct value, or does it mutate for the sake of "looking ahead?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the for loop as follows:

```
for every value of i while sum smaller or equal to n, add i to sum and increment i
```

The last part of the line `and increment i` is executed after the sum of `sum + i`, but before the next check which checks if sum is smaller or equal to n, with as result that i always is one larger than expected.

The solution could be to use a different exit (different solutions exist):

```
public static int computeIndex(int n) {
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while true {
        sum = sum + i;
        if sum<n {
          i++;
        } else break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed the fact that the sum <= n was only looked up after the value of i had been increased. I tried to incorporate your solution, however for n = 1 and n = 3 it gives me the solutions i  = 2 and i = 3 respectively, which is wrong. I'm not quite sure I see why that is since every other value I checked appears to now be correct.

Comment: The smaller equal term in there might be the reason: n=1 scenario: `sum = 1`, then if 1<=1 i++. So it seems the if should state `if sum<n`. I only clarified the reason for i to be larger than expected, did not test run my code :). Edited the answer and ran n=1,n=2, n=3 in my head. Larger numbers up to you.

Comment: van Nobelen: I just came to the same solution that it should be "<" instead of "<=" as well! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, my bad: When rewriting a loop, always check your conditions since the location where you apply them changes.

Answer (score 0):

the sum of p consecutive integers starting at 1 is p*(p+1)/2

so basically you need to solve x^2+x-2*n = 0, with solution

x = 0.5*(sqrt(1+8n)-1)